# how can i create sql database by entity framework code first in specific path

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I successfully create my database in entity framework code first using this string :

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-PL8EDEA;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;TimeOut=3600
```

This top connection string create database in default address of sql server databases
but I want the database to be saved in my desired path
I also tried this field but it was not successful

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-PL8EDEA;Initial Catalog=|D:\MyFolder|\MyDB;Integrated Security=True;TimeOut=3600
```

Comment: Hope this answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731335/how-to-specify-a-custom-folder-path-in-which-ef-code-first-approach-create-a-dat

Comment: it's true ... Thank you my dear ❤

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ef6+code+first+database+location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```